# Java 11 vs Java 17

Tags: java, java-11, java-17

I was working on a codeforces problem ([here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1807/problem/G2) and I gave up. I read the editorial and implemented the solution but it still timed out (over 2000ms) running on Java 11. Noticed that someone got it to work with a similar solution on Java 17 and it worked for me too (ran in around 300ms). Basically, I want to know what might have been added to Java to cause such a difference and if there is anyway I can change my code so that it would work on Java 11 too.

here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class Four {
    static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<t; i++) {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            long[] end = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).mapToLong(Long::parseLong).toArray();
            Arrays.sort(end);
            if (solve(end))
                sb.append("YES\n");
            else
                sb.append("NO\n");
        }
        pw.println(sb);
        pw.close();
    }

    public static boolean solve(long[] a) {
        if (a[0]!=1)
            return false;
        long sum=1;
        for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i]>sum)
                return false;
            sum+=a[i];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would guess it's something to do with the sort method or adding longs but I'm unsure. I would also think it's some weird Java 11 inefficiency and not an actual problem with the algorithm since I think my code is O(n log n) and the sum of all n is less than 10^5 as specified in the problem so it should run under 2 seconds no problem?

Comment: Will not speculate about the changes between Java versions. But generally: this is a perfect job for `Scanner` which can extract numbers from the I/O buffer without constructing `String` objects for the lines. Further, don’t create an extra `PrintWriter` for a single `println` call that you could perform on `System.out` directly. Considering that this printing is buffered anyway, you might just use `System.out.println(solve(end)? "YES": "NO");` and remove the `StringBuilder` stuff. But if you want to know for sure where the time is spent, use a profiling tool (async-profiler, preferably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to know why someone else's (e.g. Codeforce's) Java 11 and 17 **platforms** are faster / slower. You don't know what hardware they are running on, what JVM options they are using and so on. Then there is the issue that Java 11 and 17 are different ... and there are many differences between them. (3 years, 6 releases and many man-years of developer work.)

My gut feeling is that this EITHER a red-herring (i.e. platform issues) OR it is to do with JVM startup and warmup overheads.  With a difference as large as you report, I am more inclined to the former explanation.

Now the *normal* way to deal with this is to write a benchmark that runs the algorithm multiple times, eliminates the anomalous outliers, then averages the rest of them.  Use JMH or a similar framework to deal with the mechanics ...

Then run the benchmark with Java 11 and 17 on identical hardware with identical JVM options, and compare the results.  If there really is a difference between Java 11 and 17 it should show up there.   You can then investigate the cause of the difference; e.g. by profiling.

---

That the kind of problems that you do on competitive programing platforms are NOT indicative of real world Java programming.  Most real Java applications do much more complicate things, and are designed to run for a long time ... giving time for the JVM to JIT compile and optimize the code.  So ... the performance issue you are looking at here is (most likely) something that is not relevant to the kind of use-cases that Java is designed for.

This is unlikely be some "Java 11 inefficiency".